# How to redirect System out to two different JTextArea while running TestNG tests in Parallel

Tags: java, swing, logging, system, testng

We have implemented GUI using Java Swings for running Automation scripts.
For ExecutinG single Test we are able to redirect the System out to JTextArea by referencing [this link](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/redirect-standard-output-streams-to-jtextarea),
but while running Tests in parallel thru two different threads, we are unable to tarck the Sysytem out of each test separately, Logs are getting mixed in the console.

Is their any way where we can separate or redirect the System out to two different JTextArea's?

am using Win7 OS env with Selenium. TestNG, Log4j and Swings

Comment: Simply supply a second reference of a text area and echo the output to it as well...

Comment: If 2 tests are running parallely and if i echo the sys out to diff JTextArea, how will i get the logs particular to test methods in each JTextArea? Currently in my Eclipse Java console am able to see mixed logs of both test methods.

Comment: Technically, you can't.  System.out only goes to a single stream.  You "might" be able to redirect output based on the current thread

Answer (score 2):

How you decide where to target content? Is it possible to use thread id or any other parameter?

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea1;
    private JTextArea textArea2;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea1, JTextArea textArea2) {
        this.textArea1 = textArea1;
        this.textArea2 = textArea2;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        //How to recognize proper target textarea? e.g. by thread id
        if (Thread.getCurrentThread().getId()==theFirstThreadId) {
            // redirects data to the text area
            textArea1.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
            // scrolls the text area to the end of data
            textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
        }
        else {
            //the same for textArea2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but this not works in Java7 without invokeLater for append, because all thread safe methods in Swing don't exist ...

Comment: @mKorbel I just extended the behavior mentioned in the example from question